# ReadAllBytes for uploading file to Google Drive in Windows Phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have coded the Authorize part of the Uploading process, but I don't know how to upload a file after authorizing. I want to upload an image, but first I'll try with a txt file first.

```
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = "My document";
        body.Description = "A test document";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

I've found the code above everywhere on the internet. But looks like it's for windows form only as the document of System.IO.File doesn't say it supports Windows Phone. My problem began at ReadAllBytes. It said `'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAllBytes'`. So, how do I readallbytes?

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to pass MemoryStream in API as in below line of code,

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
```

then why you want to convert into byte[] ..? You can directly convert file into MemoryStream like this:

```
var a = System.IO.File.OpenRead("document.txt");
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
a.CopyTo(stream);
```

And then you can directly pass `stream` as the parameter.

```
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
request.Upload();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

Now, what i suggest is not to use `System.IO.File` in windows phone 8 instead use `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` which contains proper implementation of manipulating Files whether the file is in `InstalledLocation` or in `IsolatedStorage`

**Edit:-**

for your more information, here is how to read a file to MemoryStream:

```
        using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("document.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                ms1.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            }
        }
```

For more code, brief your scenario little more here.. Hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone (and Store Apps) use StorageFiles so you have to use different API's than System.IO.  Once you have a StorageFile, there are extension methods in the System.IO namespace that will convert an IRandomAccessStream of a StorageFile into a standard Stream that all the samples use. The sample code here uses OpenStreamForReadAsync to get a Stream. You can then get the bytes, or use the stream directly.

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    //ideally just copy this stream to the the request stream
    //or use an HttpClient and request with StreamContent(stream).

    //if you need the bytes, you can do this
    var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 }
```